# Count length of custom data attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this link with custom attribute data

```
<a class="thumb" href="" 
 data-size1="All Size"                                                            
 data-size2="25cm - 15cm"                                                           
 data-size3="20cm - 10cm"                                                                                       
 data-price1="IDR 60,000"                                                            
 data-price2="IDR 60,000"                                                            
 data-price3="IDR 60,000">
</a>
```

Actually how to count it per type like data-size = 3, data-price = 3

Thanks

i try it but not succesfull yet

```
$(this).click(function() { 
             var numItems = $('li.grid-list a.thumb-links[data-size]').length;             
             alert(numItems); 
           });
```

Comment: Using such iterated numbers in names rarely is a good idea. Can't you store the entries in a single data attribute, for example json encoded?

Comment: Not to familiar with json, could please get me the example, thx @arkascha

Comment: Sure, I wrote a short example in an answer. Hope that makes things more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON allows you to code arrays as a string. Thus you can store any number of values in a single data attribute and retrieve it with one call. This simplifies the logic.

```
<a class="thumb" href="" 
   data-size="[\"All Size\",\"25cm - 15cm\",\"20cm - 10cm\"]" 
   data-price="[\"IDR 60,000\",\"IDR 60,000\",\"IDR 60,000\"]">
    some text
</a>
```

To then work with the values you can simply decode them (a single function call) and have an array back with all it's advantages...

```
$(this).click(function(e) { 
    var dataSize = JSON.parse($(e.target).data('size'));
    var dataPrice = JSON.parse($(e.target).data('price'));
    var numItems = dataSize.length;             
    alert(numItems); 
});
```

*Note: the funny `\` characters are there to escape the quotes (`"`). They are typically generated automatically depending on how you create that anchor tag at runtime...*

Comment: Also, could it integrated with this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329522/looping-specific-attribute-on-jquery @arkascha

Comment: Certainly you can combine that. I do not fully understand that other questions topic, but I'd say you just have to revise it to use a loop, doing `dataSize.length` iterations. For each iteration you handle one entry. That way you can handle as many entries as there are coded in the data properties without having to change the code.